# Filter again in Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to filter from selected items in a subquery again?

For example: I already filtered user from a company:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE companyId = 123
```

Now I want to filter the females, the males and the user in general created this year *from the company above*. Currently I use this query:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user WHERE companyId = 123 && sex = "male") maleUser,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user WHERE companyId = 123 && sex = "female") femaleUser,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user WHERE companyId = 123 && YEAR(created) = YEAR(NOW())) currentYearUser
```

But I want to make it easier like:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM userAlreadyFilteredByCompany WHERE sex = "male") maleUser,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM userAlreadyFilteredByCompany WHERE sex = "female") femaleUser,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM userAlreadyFilteredByCompany WHERE YEAR(created) = YEAR(NOW())) currentYearUser

FROM
  (SELECT id, created FROM user WHERE companyId = 123) userAlreadyFilteredByCompany
```

Is there a way to do this? I think its easier to understand and the effort is lower when selecting on already filtered results.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN sex = "male" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as maleUser,
  SUM(CASE WHEN sex = "female" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as femaleUser,
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(created) = YEAR(NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as currentYearUser

FROM user 
WHERE companyId = 123
```

You can use CASE/WHEN adding your conditions and SUM the numbers

Comment: Or, as it's MySQL, just `SUM(sex = 'male')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(sex = "male") maleUser,
    SUM(sex = "female") femaleUser,
    SUM(YEAR(created) = YEAR(NOW())) currentYearUser
FROM user WHERE companyId = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try like this:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(if( sex = "male", 1, NULL) as maleUser,
   COUNT(if( sex = "female", 1, NULL) as femaleUser,
   COUNT( if( YEAR(created) = YEAR(NOW())), 1, NULL) as currentYearUser
FROM user
WHERE companyID = 123
```